# Bootstrap 4 Can't get element centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking on their website for a long time but I just can't find a solution, and I am a bit desperate for help right now.
I have a login form which I'm trying to get in the centre of the page. Bootstrap 4 is confusing to me compared to bootstrap 3.
I tried things like `align-self-center` or `justify-content-center`, But I just can't get it centered

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="card" style="">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Aanmelden</h3>
        <p class="card-text">Vul hier uw gegegevens in zodat u kan starten aan een geweldig avontuur op ICT-Hulp!</p>
        <form action="" class=" justify-content-center">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_name">Voornaam</label>
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Voornaam" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_lastname">Achternaam</label>
                <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Achternaam" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_email">Email</label>
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Emailadres" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_phone">Geboorte datum</label>
                <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Geboorte datum">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_phone">Wachtwoord</label>
                <input id="form_phone" type="password" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_phone">Bevestig wachtwoord</label>
                <input id="form_phone" type="password" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Bevestig wachtwoord">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary float-right" style="width: 100%" value="Aanmelden">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should minimize your code to a maximum when posting it here. As it is it's a mess to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure on what element(s) you want to center exactly, but this is how you can center a colum within a row (on md-breakpoints):

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center"> </div>
```

Change the class justify-content-md-center to another breakpoint if desired.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content

Answer (score 0):

Your ".row" is 100% width and your "col-lg-6" is 50% of the parent. You can center if either change to "col-lg-12" and use a "text-center" class there, or use for the ".card" width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;[like in this codepen][1]

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/rodrigotripp/full/KXyWyy/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this may it help you

```
<div style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; max-width: 1000px;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card" style="">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">Aanmelden</h3>
                <p class="card-text">Vul hier uw gegegevens in zodat u kan starten aan een geweldig avontuur op ICT-Hulp!</p>
                <form action="" class=" justify-content-center">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_name">Voornaam</label>
                                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Voornaam" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_lastname">Achternaam</label>
                                <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Achternaam" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_email">Email</label>
                                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Emailadres" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_phone">Geboorte datum</label>
                                <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Geboorte datum">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_phone">Wachtwoord</label>
                                <input id="form_phone" type="password" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form_phone">Bevestig wachtwoord</label>
                                <input id="form_phone" type="password" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Bevestig wachtwoord">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary float-right" style="width: 100%" value="Aanmelden">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add Your code in another div and set div style

`style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; max-width: 1000px;"`

> Also you can fix maximum width according to your screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

to center a column in `container` with `bootstrap 4`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="col-4 mx-auto" style="background:grey;height:20px;">
         </div>
    </div>
```